# What is javax.net.ssl.SSLSession creation time?

Tags: java

In our application we are currently measuring the time between `SSLSession.getCreationTime()` (Point A) and the time when we get the request from vertx framework (Point B) as a pre-request processing time by the framework.

Sometimes, the time between the two points is greater than 10 seconds (or even 20-30 seconds).

As for `javax.net.ssl.SSLSession` I would like to understand what does the timestamp returned by  getCreationTime represent? From [SSLEngine's docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html), it says `SSLSession` is available after the handshake is complete. However, it does not say when the `SSLSession` representation is created.

Does it represent

1. Timestamp in Client Hello?
2. Timestamp in Server Hello?
3. Timestamp at which the handshake is complete?
4. Or someother time.

Not sure where to look further to get more information. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The documentation seems to repeatedly suggest that a session doesn’t exist until handshaking is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This answer is purely for server end, and at the client's end, this would be different.

After looking into SSLEngine, and ServerHandshaker's source code, looks like an `SSLSession` is created at the time of when the Client Hello is received by the Server.

From [SSLSessionImpl](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/d5a00b1e8f78/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SSLSessionImpl.java#l99),

```java
private final long creationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The creation time is set during the time of creation of `SSLSessionImpl`.

And a `SSLSessionImpl` is created during client hello when the session is not a resuming session.

From [ServerHandshaker](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/ServerHandshaker.java#l699):

```java
private void clientHello(ClientHello mesg) throws IOException {
    ...
    //
    // If client hasn't specified a session we can resume, start a
    // new one and choose its cipher suite and compression options.
    // Unless new session creation is disabled for this connection!
    //
    if (session == null) {
        ...
        session = new SSLSessionImpl(protocolVersion, CipherSuite.C_NULL,
            getLocalSupportedSignAlgs(),
            sslContext.getSecureRandom(),
            getHostAddressSE(), getPortSE());
        ...
    }
}
```

And after the SSL Handshake is done, `SSLEngine` gets the `SSLSession` from the Handshaker (`ServerHandshaker` in this case).

From [SSLEngineImpl](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SSLEngineImpl.java#l1035):

```
} else if (handshaker.isDone()) {
    ...
    sess = handshaker.getSession();
    ...
}
```

#### TL;DR

An `SSLSession` is created at the server end, when the server starts processing the Client Hello. And the creation time is set to the time at which the object is created.

#### PS

Thanks for downvoting the question without explaining why. Really encourages users to ask questions in SO.